# Accesing post title and URL from Blogger gadget

Tags: javascript, blogger, diaspora

I'm trying to build a Blogger gadget for posts sharing using Diaspora!
I've started with [Diaspora Sharing Service](http://www.basshero.org/page/show/dss) usinh HTML and JavaScript  (you can take a look at my [work in progress](http://www.bit-man.com.ar/diaspora.xml)) and found that URL and TITLE are empty

Neither accessing url  using post.url or window.location.href can I obtain a valid value.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could provide more information? It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking, so it might not be clear to others, too.

Comment: Thanks Erin. Inside a Blogger gadget I need to access the blog URL to be sent to a social network (diaspora in my gadget) and being published. At https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/gadgets/gadgets_for_blogger is shown how to access the post feed url, comment url or any other but not the post url. I've tried using "post.url" and "window.location.href" but didn't work for me.

Comment: I use `data:post.url` myself, and it works pretty well. There can be some issues depending on variables, but I find it to be reliable enough. Still, have you tried `data:post.sharePostUrl`? I've used it before, but with varied results. Maybe for your purposes the results will be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

As the author of DSS I have to point out that I have some time ago ramped it down. Instead anyone wanting a similar service should use the [Diaspora* Advanced Sharer](http://sharetodiaspora.github.com/about/) which is based on DSS.

As for the question on how to get it working with Blogger, D*AS has instructions for this;

---

**Blogger blogs**

This method will include a Diaspora* share button next to Google +1 button. It is necessary to enable the sharing buttons.

- Enter your dashboard and choose your blog.
- In section Template, click on Edit HTML. If a warning appears, click Continue.
- Check Expand widget templates, press Ctrl+F and write sharebuttons.
- Find the line `<b:includable id='shareButtons' var='post'>`. Just after that, copy the following code:

`<a expr:href='"http://sharetodiaspora.github.com/?url=" + data:post.url + "&title=" + data:post.title' target='_blank' title='Share on Diaspora'>
    <img src='http://joindiaspora.com/favicon.ico' style='width:16px; height:16px; padding:0; border:0; vertical-align:middle;'/>
</a>`

---

Ps. Found this question from my Apache error logs :P